# Realtime audio input and output streaming in ios

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

am newbie for multimedia work.i want to capture audio by samples and transfer to some other ios device via network.how to start my work??? .i have just gone through apple multi media guide and speakhere example ,it is full of c++ code and they are writing in file and then start services ,but i need buffer...please help  me to start my work in correct way .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just spent a bunch of time working on real time audio stuff you can use AudioQueue but it has latency issues around 100-200ms.

If you want to do something like the t-pain app, you have to use

- RemoteIO API
- Audio Unit API

They are equally difficult to implement, so I would just pick the **remote IO** path.

Source can be found here:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Comment: @madmik3 : to record and playback can i use AudioQueue??

Comment: You can, but it has latency issues like I described above and you can also use the RemoteIO Audio Unit API like in the link provided. They are two different APIs that do recording and playback in iOS.

Comment: @madmik3: Which frameWork is best , to start Audio call in ios. AVtoolkit/AVFoundation or some other

Comment: sorry still not sure what you are asking for. can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted the answer above, but I wanted to add a piece of information that took me a while to figure out. When using AudioQueue for recording, the intuitive notion is that the callback is done in regular intervals of whatever the number of samples represent. That notion is incorrect, AudioQueue seems to gather the samples for a long period of time, then deliver them in very fast iterations of the callback.

In my case, I was doing 20ms samples, and receiving 320 samples per callback. When printing out the timestamps for the call, I noticed a pattern of: 1 call every 2 ms, then after a while one call of ~180ms. Since I was doing VoIP, this presented the symptom of an increasing delay on the receiving end. Switching to Remote I/O seems to have solved the issue.